# Bespoke SQL Server 'encoding' sproc - is there a neater way of doing this?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm just wondering if there's a better way of doing this in SQL Server 2005.

Effectively, I'm taking an originator_id (a number between 0 and 99) and a 'next_element' (it's really just a sequential counter between 1 and 999,999).
We are trying to create a 6-character 'code' from them.

The originator_id is multiplied up by a million, and then the counter added in, giving us a number between 0 and 99,999,999.

Then we convert this into a 'base 32' string - a fake base 32, where we're really just using 0-9 and A-Z but with a few of the more confusing alphanums removed for clarity (I, O, S, Z).

To do this, we just divide the number up by powers of 32, at each stage using the result we get for each power as an index for a character from our array of selected character.

```
Thus, an originator ID of 61 and NextCodeElement of 9 gives a code of '1T5JA9'

(61 * 1,000,000) + 9 = 61,000,009
61,000,009 div (5^32 = 33,554,432) =  1 = '1'
27,445,577 div (4^32 =  1,048,576) = 26 = 'T'
   182,601 div (3^32 =     32,768) =  5 = '5'
    18,761 div (2^32 =      1,024) = 18 = 'J'
       329 div (1^32 =         32) = 10 = 'A'
         9 div (0^32 =          1) =  9 = '9'

so my code is 1T5JA9
```

Previously I've had this algorithm working (in Delphi) but now I really need to be able to recreate it in SQL Server 2005.  Obviously I don't quite have the same functions to hand that I have in Delphi, but this is my take on the routine. It works, and I can generate codes (or reconstruct codes back into their components) just fine.

But it looks a bit long-winded, and I'm not sure that the trick of selecting the result of a division into an int (ie casting it, really) is necessarily 'right' - is there a better SQLS approach to this kind of thing?

```
CREATE procedure dummy_RP_CREATE_CODE @NextCodeElement int, @OriginatorID int,
  @code varchar(6) output
as
begin
  declare @raw_num int;
  declare @bcelems char(32);
  declare @chr int;

  select @bcelems='0123456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRTUVWXY';
  select @code='';

  -- add in the originator_id, scaled into place
  select @raw_num = (@OriginatorID * 1000000) + @NextCodeElement;

  -- now to convert this to a 6-char code

  -- 5^32
  select @chr = @raw_num / 33554432;
  select @raw_num = @raw_num - (@chr * 33554432);
  select @code = @code + SUBSTRING(@bcelems, 1 + @chr, 1);

  -- 4^32
  select @chr = @raw_num / 1048576;
  select @raw_num = @raw_num - (@chr * 1048576);
  select @code = @code + SUBSTRING(@bcelems, 1 + @chr, 1);

  -- 3^32
  select @chr = @raw_num / 32768;
  select @raw_num = @raw_num - (@chr * 32768);
  select @code = @code + SUBSTRING(@bcelems, 1 + @chr, 1);

  -- 2^32
  select @chr = @raw_num / 1024;
  select @raw_num = @raw_num - (@chr * 1024);
  select @code = @code + SUBSTRING(@bcelems, 1 + @chr, 1);

  -- 1^32
  select @chr = @raw_num / 32;
  select @raw_num = @raw_num - (@chr * 32);
  select @code = @code + SUBSTRING(@bcelems, 1 + @chr, 1);

  -- 0^32  
  select @code = @code + SUBSTRING(@bcelems, 1 + @raw_num, 1);

  -- that's it!
end;
```

I'm not desperately concerned about optimisation unless this method is actually an order of magnitude (or so) worse than any alternative.

The code only ever gets executed in small bursts, maybe generating 20 or 30 codes every 10 minutes or so. Because of the large range of numbers I don't want to pre-calculate the codes into a huge table (only small pockets of the overall code range will be used in any given installation).

However, I'm sure there's probably a tidier way of achieving the same result - particularly those divisions and subtractions.

Any constructive criticism, observations or suggestions would be most welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seeing as it's SQL Server 2005, any reason not to use a CLR stored procedure? You could use your CLR language of choice then and it'd probably be a relatively direct port of your existing Delphi code.

Comment: Thanks - I simply hadn't considered that!  

I'll read-up on how to install/deploy something like that and see how it fits in with the rest of our solution.

Answer (score 0):

Although it can clearly be done in SQL Server 2005, I think that it's of sufficient 'non-database-ness' that some kind of precompiled, high-level language routine makese sense.

I've written DLLs for Interbase/Firebird, and T-SQL sprocs for SQL Server, but never a CLR routine. It will be an interesting exercise!